# How to Store HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> to SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have to store the HashMap value on SQLite with Keyset  and reuse when application is restart using shared preference.

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> hashMap;
hashMap = new HashMap<>();
//Insert Value
hashMap.put(btn.getId(), listValue);
// Read a Value
Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry = (Map.Entry<Integer,   ArrayList<String>>) iteratorMap.next();

for (Integer ihashId :hashMap.keySet()) {
    if( btnid == ihashId)
     {
       Set<Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>> setMap = hashMap.entrySet();
       Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer,  ArrayList<String>>> iteratorMap =  setMap.iterator();
       while (iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry = (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>) iteratorMap.next();
             ArrayList<String> values = entry.getValue();
             if (btnId == entry.getKey()) {
               getSetName.setText(values.get(0));
               getSetAddress.setText(values.get(1));
               getSetPin.setText(values.get(2));
               getSetValue.setText(values.get(3));
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: how big is your array list?

Comment: This is a terrible use of ArrayList.

Comment: @AC-OpenSource In SQLite, reading the hashvalues
  hashDb = setValue.hashMapValue;
        setMap = setValue.hashMapValue.entrySet();
        iteratorMap = setMap.iterator();
        while (iteratorMap.hasNext()) {
            entry = (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>>) iteratorMap.next();
            values = entry.getValue();
            content.put(Name, getValue.name);
            content.put(Address, getValue.address);
            content.put(Pin, getValue.pin_Detail);
            content.put(Value, getValue.valu);
  } And also having common column values.how to insert each record?

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer Before Question Edited:**
HashMap is already serialized so you can store the HashMap directly on your sqlite database as a BLOB. Although you won't be able to read it's content until you de-serialize it.

**EDIT:** 
You should put long running operations inside an async task. If you want the the reference to your variables to survive configuration changes, you should use a fragment and use `setRetainInstance(true)` although regardless of keeping your reference to the AsyncTask, it is independent of the UI thread and will keep running.

**SIDE NOTE:**
Always use manually counted loop when using ArrayList as it has better performance.

As seen in [this comparison](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/26/performance-comparison-of-different-for-loops-in-java/), using for loop with counter set to the size of the array is significantly faster than for each loop:

```
private static List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int j = list.size(); j > size ; j--)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76994/discussion-on-answer-by-ac-opensource-how-to-store-hashmapinteger-arrayliststr).